# Suppose $A = U\Sigma U^T$. If $A$ is not invertible, is it correct to write $A^{-1} = (U\Sigma U^T)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is symmetric and thus, orthogonally diagonalizable: $A = U\Sigma U^T$, where $UU^T = I$ and $U^TU = I$. $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

Suppose $A$ is not invertible, then would it be correct to write the following?
$$A^{-1} = (U\Sigma U^T)^{-1} = U\Sigma^{-1}U^T$$

A follow-up question is about how one might express the pseudoinverse of $A$ in terms of $U$ and $\Sigma$. Please see the edit below.

**Edit**: Suppose $A = U\Sigma V^T$ by singular value decomposition. Now $A$ may or may not be symmetric. How can I express the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $A^{+}$ in terms of $U, \Sigma, V$?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?..

Comment: Given that $A$ is not invertible, then why does it make sense to write down $A^{-1}$?

Comment: That's what I figured. So would it be more appropriate to write it in terms of pseudoinverse of $A$ instead? If so, can I express the pseudoinverse of $A$ in terms of $U$ and $\Sigma$?

Comment: In general no, and there are many versions of pseudo-inverses. If you are talking about the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse $A^+$, there does have a way to express $A^+$ in terms of $U, \Sigma, V$, where $A = U\Sigma V$ is the singular value decomposition of $A$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I would be interested in seeing how to express $A^+$ in terms of $U, \Sigma$, and $V$ if possible. I've edited my original post to reflect this. Please feel free to add an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Then you need to edit your condition to $A = U\Sigma V$ as well. In fact, in that case, $A$ doesn't have to be symmetric at all, because any matrix admits a singular value decomposition.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Sure, just edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\diag}{\mathrm{diag}}$

To its most generality, assume $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, and let $A = U\Sigma V$ be the SVD of $A$, where $U$ and $V$ are order $m$ and $n$ unitary matrices respectively, and
$$\Sigma = \diag(\diag(\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_r), 0, \ldots, 0), $$
and $\mu_1 \geq \mu_2 \geq \cdots \geq \mu_r > 0$ are all (positive) singular values of $A$.

It is then straightforward to verify that
$$A^+ = V^*\diag(\diag(\mu_1^{-1}, \mu_2^{-1}, \ldots, \mu_r^{-1}), 0, \ldots, 0)U^*$$
is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$. Here $V^*$ means the conjugate transpose of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ will fail to be invertible when one of its eigenvalues is $0$. Then that will be one of the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$, which is thus itself not invertible.

Since the transformation is just changing the underlying coordinate system, rewriting the matrix this way can't change any geometric property the linear transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is symmetric, but not necessarily definite positive. If it isn't definite (has a null eigenvalue) it is not invertible.

In the case it IS definite, then it is invertible, and by the law $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$; you can deduce that:

$$A^{-1} = (U\Sigma U^T)^{-1} = (U^{T})^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}U^{-1} = U\Sigma^{-1}U^T$$

If it isn't invertible/definite; then this equation does not hold, since $\Sigma^{-1}$ is undefined.